# How can I bind a background color in WPF dynamically?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I cannot bind the background dynamically because it raises exception " A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'Binding'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApplication.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApplication"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" x:Key="customColorBrush"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Background="{Binding Source={DynamicResource customColorBrush}}" Margin="20"></Button>
    <Button Background="{Binding Source={StaticResource customColorBrush}}" Margin="20" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You should better use Bindings for MVVM structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your binding to remove the 'Binding' keyword from your DynamicResource and StaticResource declaration.

Update to:

```
 <Button Background="{DynamicResource customColorBrush}" Margin="20"></Button>
 <Button Background="{StaticResource customColorBrush}" Margin="20" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
```

Note:

You should probably use only StaticResource here, as it appears you are not changing the Background color during run-time. DynamicResource is typically used to dynamically load the resource during run-time during the first time it is accessed, or if you want to do run-time switching (i.e., theme/theme switching). If you simply using it once, StaticResource is just fine (the brush will get applied during compile time).